# Mixing Subversion "SVNParentPath" and per-repository configurations?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, http, version-control, authorization

Given a typical Subversion/Apache configuration using SVNParentPath, with repositories hosted
under `/svn/` like this:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn

    SVNParentPath /srv/source/svn/repos
    SVNReposName "Subversion Repository"

    AuthzSVNAccessFile /srv/source/svn/authz
    Satisfy Any

    AuthType                Basic
    AuthBasicProvider       file
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /srv/source/svn/htpasswd

    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Is there a way to override this configuration for specific
repositories *without* having to host them at a different path?  That
is, is there any way I can add a `Location` block like this...

```
<Location /svn/my_special_repo>
    SVNPath /srv/source/svn/repos/my_special_repo
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /srv/source/svn/repos/my_special_repo/conf/authz
</Location>
```

...and have it *override* the configuration provided in the
`Location` block for `/svn`? My attempts at doing this with the above
configuration have been met with weird and unhelpful errors in the
Apache error log, such as:

```
[Wed Feb 02 11:28:35 2011] [error] [client 10.10.209.120]
(20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/srv/source/svn/repos/svn/format':
No such file or directory
```

All this seems to be mod_dav_svn's way of telling me that I can't do
what I'm trying to do.  I'm open to solutions or alternatives!

**EDIT**: Well, I can see that this question has generated a lot of excitement among the readership.  For the record, what I may end up doing is generating per-repository configurations for all of our existing repositories, and then abandoning the `SVNParentPath` based configuration.  The per-repo Apache configuration is minimal, especially using something like [mod_macro](http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/mod_macro/); the hard part will be splitting apart the global authz file.  If you've done this before, tips are appreciated.

Comment: I've got the same problem, and solved it by using mod_macro. Thanks!!!
(It seems to be an old bug in either Apache or Subversion.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to see my own question languishing there in the unanswered questions list, so here's what we did:

- In our main server configuration, we have:

  ```
    <Location /svn/>
          SVNParentPath /srv/source/svn/repos
    </Location>
  ```
- We adopted the following `mod_macro` to replicate this behavior for new repositories:

  ```
  <Macro LegacySubversionRepo $name>
      # Override SVNParentPath block in main vhost config.
      RewriteRule ^/svn/$name /repo/$name [PT]

      <Location /repo/$name>
              Order                   deny,allow
              Allow                   from all

              Use LdapAuth \
                      "$name svn repository" \
                      /srv/source/svn/htpasswd

              DAV svn
              SVNPath /srv/source/svn/repos/$name
              AuthzSVNAccessFile /srv/source/svn/authz
              SVNAutoversioning On
              Satisfy Any
      </Location>
  </Macro>
  ```

  The `RewriteRule` allows the repository configuration to override the `<Location /svn/>` in the main config that would otherwise match the request.

With this in place, it becomes relatively easily to adopt per-repository authentication and authorization configuration (instead of the global `htpasswd` file used here).

Comment: mod_macro rocks